# Wcf referenced Class code update

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wcf

I am new to wpf and wcf C# application development and stuck into updating the class where wcf service is referenced. For example, Service has a class of testDbConnect and has various service operation contracts functions defined and implemented in iservice.cs and service.cs. Then in wpf class , this service is added as a reference and works perfect when calls the service functions by button click operation. Like this is what I am testing on button click.

```
        Service1Client service = new Service1Client();

        if (service.Testdb() == 1)  //Testdb is the function in service which is only returning 1
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hello there");
        }
```

The problem I am facing, It perfectly starts service and show the message box( hello there) on button click but when I am updating the code even inside the button click , it still keep showing the hello there message box and not updating code. Maybe there is some proxy generation included but I am not understanding it. It'll be great If someone could explain me in easy words and tell me how It could be solved. Thanks

Comment: Where you are actually updating your code in service or client ?can you share some code which you try to update, and still showing hello there?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the way you're consuming your WCF Service you need to update your services references.

Suppose you need to rename `int Testdb();` in your service for `int TestDb();`. You go to your contract (IService1.cs), change the signature to match:

**IService1.cs**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    int TestDb();
}
```

Then go to your service and update your method:
**Service1.cs**

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public int TestDb()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Then, on the server side your good to go, but you need to update your service reference on your client app, so your proxies reflect the new method signature. So in your client app you expand Service References folder, right-click **ServiceReference1** - or the name of your service reference - node and select Update Service Reference.

[image: Updating services references]

Let Visual Studio update the service reference and then you should be able to call the `TestDb` method by the new name.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi . Thank you a lot for your reply. I tried this and now getting the following exception  

Additional information: The message with Action 'http://tempuri.org/IService1/InsertTestdb' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.  Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).

Comment: Where you able to update the reference correctly. VS show any errors? This error indicates that you might have different contracts for the client and the server.

Comment: Look, I've put together a sample for you. [Take a look](https://github.com/ktamayop/WcfSample). Let me know how this works for you.

Comment: Thank you sir karel. Your given example works totally fine . Now I'll try it with my code if it works.